# Apache version check fails

Tags: apache2

Apache 2 is installed in the `/etc` directory. But when I use `httpd -v` from the terminal, it gives an error stating httpd command not found. How do I fix this error?

Platform: Linux (SUSE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it is because you are not in the user environment that has the command.

For example, if you were root, you could `su -` and then try `httpd -v`.

Otherwise, use the full path. In my case it is this:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -v
```

It may be somewhere different on your system, but that is the location of that particular file even though my installation is located here: `/etc/httpd/`

Answer (score 0):

The location of `httpd` can be found out like that:
Just type in your terminal:

```
# whereis httpd
```

And you should see something like that

```
 # whereis httpd   
 httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd /etc/httpd
```

That would be you path to apache programm.
If you are not an admin or not part of sudoer's group the outputs of this program are limited.
You won't be able to read, check, configure most configuration files. That happens to all who had shared hosting accounts with ssh access. Only some basic data available. anything that requires root access will give you errors:

```
#/usr/sbin/httpd -V
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 63: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 64: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 65: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Or like that:

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -S
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 63: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 64: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 65: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
httpd: Could not open configuration file /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Permission denied
```

P.S.
BTW, Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) doesn't recommend to invoke `httpd` programm directly, instead use `apachectl`